# Adding a Image Within a switch - PaintComponent Override

Tags: java, image, swing, switch-statement, paintcomponent

Im trying to add a small burger.jpg img to a game I am making. The burger should be added whenever 'f'(food) is passed in Switch. Im having issues implementing this in my code.

I was originally just filling an orange rectangle `g2.fillRect()`, but I would like to replace this with an actual image instead. I've tried scaling the image and adding it but it doesn't show up. If I replace the`g2.fillRect` at the end of the for loop, it makes every square a burger, instead of just the 'f'

How would I do this?

```
private class Game extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage img = null;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2) {

        super.paintComponent(g2);

        try {

            img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/burger.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedImage otherImage = new BufferedImage(50, 50,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = otherImage.createGraphics();

        int width = getWidth() / game.getBoardWidth();
        int height = getHeight() / game.getBoardHeight();

        char[] symbols = game.toString().toCharArray();

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        for (char c : symbols) {

            switch (c) {
            case 'Q':
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                break;
            case 'H':
                g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case 'f':
                //g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                g2.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, null);
                break;
            case '-':
                g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;
            case '\n':
                y += height;
                x = 0; 
            }

           //g2.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, null);
           g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            x += width;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested yet, but this is what is happening right now in your program:

1. Get a symbol

   - if (`'f'`) then `drawImage` then `fillRect`

What you want is:

1. Get a symbol

   - if(`'f'`) then `drawImage` otherwise `fillRect`

So you compare:

```
if (symbol == 'f') {
    g2.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, null);
} else {
    g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}
```

Or what I'd do is:

```
switch (c) {
    case 'Q':
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        break;
    case 'H':
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        break;
    case 'f':
        //g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g2.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, null);
        break;
    case '-':
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        break;
    case '\n':
        y += height;
        x = 0; 
}
```

And comment out or remove the last call to:

```
g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
```

---

### TIP:

```
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/burger.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Those lines should be in the constructor, not in the `paintComponent` method, it gets called by Swing several times, doing so might slow or block / freeze your application until it finishes reading it.

Also, you're not using `otherImage` variable so you can delete it as well...

Comment: That worked great @Frakcool. Thanks. Would you recommend another way to read in an image?

Comment: Yes, as an [`embedded-resource`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) and it's encouraged to do it that way as well but as I said, do it once in the constructor